# Why server request response time in iOS more than Android?

Tags: php, android, ios

I am working on iOS app development. I noticed that when request to server from iPhone it's take more time compare to Android device request-response time. For both, I use same rest API with same server but response times are difference(minimum 2-5 second late response in iPhone device comparing to Android device).

In iOS I use AFNetworking, in android AsyncHTTPClient library and server side PHP used.

Comment: If you server side (PHP) doesn't differentiate the client fetching it, then the issue should resides on the client's (phone) side. And that possibility could range from anything, from the iOS/Android way of implementing the fetch till the devices spec etc. You need to drill down further to the issue more specifically.

Comment: Main problem generating when uploading image. In iPhone it's take more time to upload to server.

Comment: Same here! The response in Android is faster 1-3s